# Replace hardcoded values

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

The task requirement is to replace a certain hardcoded keywords in a relatively large application with new keywords read from the back-end database.

These keywords are common in the application and are found mostly in .aspx pages, .ascx control pages and their code-behind .cs pages. They are usually embedded in

1. HTML, e.g. `<span>An old keyword</span>`
2. ASP/Rad Controls,
   e.g. `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="An old
   keyword"></asp:Label>`
3. JS and Code behind with hard-coded string values

As we are talking about a couple of hundreds existing pages here, I wonder if there's an efficient way to carry out this task.

Also, I'd like to know if I can take advantage of the master pages, as many .aspx pages are using master page templates. Perhaps, I can put some code in the master pages, search the keywords in its content and replace them with new keywords. But is it possible?

Comment: How about a handler? Seems like it would be a good way to tackle it.

Comment: Hi There, Interesting Question. I would go with Regex to start with

Comment: Why would you replace the old keywords every time a page is rendered with some other keywords, which probably will be replaced by the actual values? Isn't it a better solution to parse the files one time and save them with the new keywords?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please, phillip? Thanks.

Comment: @NipunAmbastha Care to share why? This should/could only need to be done once, and regex might just be _adding_ complexity.

Comment: I see your point, Alex, but the new keywords are dynamic as they are from the database, and the user can change these keywords as they feel like.

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/13/Capturing-and-Transforming-ASPNET-Output-with-ResponseFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is going to diverge from your request, only so as to try and tackle the problem directly, though, rather than be a crutch for your current implementation. If these "keywords" exist and need to be replaced every time with dynamic values, then the initial keyword values need not exist anyway.

Therefore, you could use `Literal` controls and instead of doing some search & replace method with *each page load*, you can just pull in the dynamic values to `someLiteral.Text`.

Granted, your heavy use of the planted keywords make this no small feat initially - a search & replace mode could well suit you here for this one-off task - but in the long run this is much more versatile and less resource intensive.